# Flex Grid like my Picture

Tags: html, css, flexbox, c1flexgrid

I have tried to make it look like the below picture, but I can not do it.
Everytime he put it right on or under the big col -.-

[Grid System Picture I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaorF.jpg)

**Here is my code:**

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 1 8%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* nested grids */
.row .row, .row.nested {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}

/* full width grids */
.row.wide-fit {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

/* center grids */
.row.center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.center .col {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

/* columns widths */

.col-span-1 {
  flex-basis: 8.3333%;
}

.col-span-2 {
  flex-basis: 16.6666%; 
}

.col-span-3 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.col-span-4 {
  flex-basis: 33.3333%;
}

.col-span-5 {
  flex-basis: 41.6666%;
}

.col-span-6 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.col-span-7 {
  flex-basis: 58.3333%;
}

.col-span-8 {
  flex-basis: 66.6666%;
}

.col-span-9 {
  flex-basis: 75%;
}

.col-span-10 {
  flex-basis: 83.3333%;
}

.col-span-11 {
  flex-basis: 91.6666%;
}

.col-span-12 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

/* examples */

.fixed-width {
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.1) !important;
}

@media all and (max-width: 568px) {
  .col-span-1,
  .col-span-2,
  .col-span-3,
  .col-span-4,
  .col-span-5 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }

  .col-span-6,
  .col-span-7,
  .col-span-8,
  .col-span-9,
  .col-span-10,
  .col-span-11 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }

  .nested .col {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  
}

/* eye candy */

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.row {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.col {
  background-color: #999999;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Flexbox Grid System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fb-grid.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col col-span-8">1</div>
 <div class="col col-span-2">2</div>
 <div class="col col-span-2">3</div>
  <div class="col col-span-4">4</div>
  <div class="col col-span-4">5</div>
  <div class="col col-span-4">6</div>
</div>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: What have you tried? Please specify the exact coding problem that you are trying to solve. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using? do you want  fixed height columns?

Comment: Have you tried with `min-height` on the top div  wrapper?

Comment: @grizzthedj i know it was only a question oO?

Comment: v4 alpha and yes i tried with heights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML code will looks like

```
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Flexbox Grid System</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fb-grid.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-span-8">1</div> <!-- give required height-->
        <div class="col col-span-4">
            <div class="col col-span-12">2</div><!--code change-->
            <div class="col col-span-12">3</div><!--code change-->
        </div>
      <div class="col col-span-4">4</div>
      <div class="col col-span-4">5</div>
      <div class="col col-span-4">6</div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, i think it gave another method but this is ok :)